# How to customise a Siri shortcut in the shortcuts app

Tags: swift, xcode, siri, sirikit, sirishortcuts

### How do you customise a Siri shortcut in the shortcuts app?

*This question is related to the new iOS 12 feature: Siri Shortcuts. Users can use Siri shortcuts to trigger app specific features (created by the developer) either through a custom defined voice phrase or within the new iOS 12 "Shortcuts" app. The shortcut app allows you to create workflows by combining shortcuts from apps, similar to the Automator app on your Mac.*

In our app we implemented a shortcut for a specific feature. This means that users can trigger this shortcut by voice or within the shortcuts app to execute this feature. Our shortcut is made available "Automagically" in the Shortcuts app of iOS by donating our Intent to Siri.

The question is, how do I customise this Shortcut? By default our Shortcut looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the shortcut only shows the Label Transfer "X" to "X" and doesn't allow you to configure this shortcut. When I compare my shortcut to other shortcuts from other apps I see that those shortcuts are configurable, like a shortcut from the app "Giphy":

[image]

This shortcut allows you to configure the "search", "show GIF picker" and "select multiple". Also notice the variables at the bottom of the screen, for example the **Ask When Run** variable.

I can't find any documentation on how to configure a shortcut. In the sample code of Apple (SoupChef) they also don't provide configurable shortcuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature was exclusive for some companies on iOS 12. In iOS 13  it's possible for anyone to customise your Siri Intents. More information can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sirikit/adding_user_interactivity_with_siri_shortcuts_and_the_shortcuts_app).